# Need a alternative to Surveygizmo / alchemer

Tags: data, survey, r

I have been using Surveygizmo for 5 years and it has been mostly great but in the last year. There has been several incidences of downtime without good support. The number one requirement is to be able to collect data so I need to find alternative.

Alternative needs API webhooks server side scripting - SG has lua - this is needed to parse webhook returns in real time Aesthetically agreeable
Connection to R would be nice also

I have tried qualtrics as they are a big player but only supports client-side javascript which is slow and limited.

thank you for your time